# preventing screen sizes to open a site

Tags: javascript, css, web-deployment

I was wondering if it is possible to prevent some screens of showing the contents of my site ?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
body {
   /* Hide Content Or Whatever*/
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that via

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
body {
   display: none
}}
```

Note: @media queries aren't supported by IE8 and below

Comment: You can also hide everything with the [wildcard * selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.asp)

Comment: @T30 I am refererring to OP's hint in the question, there a tons of solution to this problem actually, it all depends on what he wants.